# Is it possible to redirect the url with same parameter and different base url by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i am trying to redirect the the url with same parameter and different base url i tried so many ways but nothing is working, the url is redirecting but the parameters are not passing to new url is there any way to redirect the url with parameter,

OLD URL

http://oldsite.com/cancelacion.php?idioma=XX&busqueda_id=XXXXX&session=XXXXXXXXXXX

NEW URL

http://newsite.com/cancelacion.php?idioma=XX&busqueda_id=XXXXX&session=XXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Yes it is possible and it's pretty much clear how to solve this from the apache docs here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html chapter 'Resource Moved to Another Server'

Answer (score 1):

The Apache module **mod_rewrite** allows you to rewrite URL.
First of all, you need enabled **mod_rewrite**. On Ubuntu, for example, you can check it via `sudo apache2ctl -M | grep rewrite_module` command. If output is empty install module via command `sudo a2enmod mod_rewrite`

After that, in the root, *oldsite.com* put this .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is entirely possible, You can use simply to RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch "http://oldsite.com/cancelacion.php(.*)" "http://newsite.com/cancelacion.php(.*)"
```